# Apply background color to all labels in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code that will change the background color of a specific label in a `GridView`, and that works all well and good.

```
protected void HighLight_Hours(Label Quarter)
{
    Int32 Hours;
    Int32.TryParse(Quarter.Text, out Hours);
    switch (Hours)
    {
        case 0:
            Quarter.BackColor = Color.Red;
            break;
        case 1:
            Quarter.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            break;
        case 2:
            Quarter.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            break;
    }
}
```

But instead of calling my function for every single label in my Grid (there are a lot, one for every 15 minutes in a day) is there a way to loop through all the contents of the `GridView` and set the color accordingly?

Comment: Are you using a `GridView`?  If so, it sounds like you might want to do this in the [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

Comment: @jadarnel27:  That is where I am currently doing it, but I have to reference each label by name.

Comment: Is there only one label per row?  Why don't you want to specify the label by name?  What if down the road, you add another label to each row and then you will run into problems.

Comment: @Saied: No, there are 98 labels per row. (yes, i know that is a crazy lot)

Comment: @Limey - I think if there are 98 labels per row, you need to specify the id of the label when looping through the rows.

Comment: @Limey - That is more than crazy :). Is this some legacy app built from one StrinBuilder?

Comment: @Saied: No, its brand new.  my clients want to break the day down in 15 minute increments for scheduling.  I am making sure it supports 98, but it really will only show about half of that (still crazy, but required)

Comment: Well, if that is the case, then @felipeoriani answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 protected void gv_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            foreach (DataControlFieldCell dcfc in e.Row.Controls)
            {
                DataControlFieldCell dataControlFieldCell = dcfc;

                foreach(var control in dataControlFieldCell.Controls)
                    if (control is Label)
                        HighLight_Hours((Label) control);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // read in all controls of a row
        foreach (var control in e.Row.Controls)
        {
            // check if the control is a label
            if (control is Label)
            {
                // call your function and cast the control to a Label
                HighLight_Hours((Label) control);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is dependent on if there is only one label per row.

Comment: But doesn't the foreach loop take care of that?  This solution should allow his code to check each control and call the highlight function for each one that solves to a Label.

Comment: @Marshall - Right, but is it all the labels in the row or just a specific label?

Comment: hmmm...this doesn't work.  var control will always be a DataControlFieldCell.  I am trying to see if i can dig a level lower for the label.

Comment: @Limey If that's the case, you would probably just have to nest another foreach loop (to loop through the controls collection of each DataControlFieldCell).

Comment: @jadarnel27:  that won't work cause control variable doesn't have GetEnumerator.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
foreach (DataGridItem CurrentItem in SomeKindOfDataGrid.Items)
     CurrentItem.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Andrew

Comment: OP is using a `GridView`, not a `DataGrid`.  How old school of you ;-)

Comment: @Saied The `GridView` has been around since ASP.NET 2.0.  So DataGrid would be prior to 2004 / 2005 I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse in following event and get control, rought like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        { 
             foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                       foreach (Control ctrl in gvr.Controls)   
                     {

                          Label lbl = (Label )e.Row.FindControl("yourlabel");
                          lbl.ForeColor =system.drawing.color.red;


                        }
               }
        }
```

Comment: He wants to get the label without knowing the name, but that only works if there is one label per row, so this solution is good so far.